# How can I improve this question about police reform?

Tags: discussion, scope

I asked a question that I was advised to narrow down, and after initially found the suggestion frustrating since it's a question that's difficult to ask in a narrow, succinct way. It's a big topic, but I believe Politics Stack Exchange is a community uniquely capable of delivering answers not plagued by the polarized opinions presented when I bring up the topic in a less academic environment.

[The question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/61939/how-can-police-be-held-accountable-for-wrongdoing-without-deterring-their-abilit) is now titled:

> "How can police be held accountable for wrongdoing without deterring
> their ability to enforce the law?"

And asks:

> How can police be held accountable for wrongdoing without deterring
> their ability to enforce the law? To narrow down the scope of this
> question, I'm looking for political avenues at the state level of
> government.

But since editing I've received a second close vote, so I'm looking for direction of how I might further narrow / improve it.

Comment: Since you asked this, the scope was narrowed to be about only Federal actions, and the question was reopened but then closed as a duplicate. Is this meta question out of date (because you already made changes) or are you asking how to improve it to get it reopened again?

Comment: @divibisan Out of date. I could argue its different from the other question in the sense that it asks about specific problems related to the topic the other question doesn't (and answers mostly don't address), or I could change it to focus on one of those. If I were to change it again I should probably delete it and make a new one

Comment: Yeah, if you can think of a better way to highlight the differences from the duplicate, I'd recommend just making a new question, rather than editing this one. You should mention [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/56747/19301) and briefly explain why your new question is distinct, to make the differences more clear. There's no need to delete your original question, though.